# Any way to listen to 2 hosts with same IP (192.168.1.1) on different NICs, Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, networking, routing

The problem is we have one computer (Ubuntu 18.04) that is going to have to communicate with a server on a 192.168.1.0 LAN and from a **different** NIC is going to have to **receive** UDP packets over 10G Ethernet from a device whose IP is set to 192.168.1.1. The LAN's gateway is also 192.168.1.1.   We don't control the LAN and the owner won't change it.  We want to change the IP address of the device but, thus far, no help from the manufacturer.

(Edit) An additional difficulty is that the computer and the device that sends UDP are inside a standardized case, that is full.  We are not allowed to use a different case.  We are not allowed to add equipment outside the case.

Not believing it would be this simple, we did consider the possibility that the routing table was only for sending and not receiving.  Since we never send from the Ubuntu box to the device, we decided to try to delete the route.  Disconnect our test LAN.  Then watched for incoming UDP packets.  Worked.  Deleted the route.  Packets stop.  Add route, packets start.  Unfortunately when we connect to the LAN, the system won't work.

Research -- Using [namespaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/705919/the-same-ip-on-multiple-interfaces/706274#706274) was the first article I found.  I kept searching.  While most weren't good fits, several led me back to the same namespaces article.  The problem is that the same program/process that listens and processes UDP packets then needs to send results to a server on the 192.168.1.0 LAN.  I don't think we can use 2 name spaces at the exact same time in the same process.

Then we also thought about trying to process the incoming UPD using a "wireshark" approach.  We do see the packets even with the route deleted.  However, that failed because user space filtering is too slow.

Is there a solution based on that we only want to receive UPD (never send) on the 10G interface?  Or perhaps is there a way to get one program to have access to two network namespaces at the same time? Anything else?

(It is possible that the manufacturer will still get back to us with a way to change the IP of the "UPD device" which will make all this moot.)

Comment: You can always put a router in line with one of the networks and use network address translation.

Comment: Thanks @Appleoddity.  Tells me I should have better explained the problem.  It's an embedded system.  The computer and the device that sends UDP packets is in the box.  The box is full.  We can't add something outside the box.  I'll edit my question to correct my omission.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense, but then you can put a router inline with the LAN side of the network. The existing 192.168.1.x would be behind the router and a different network would be presented to the LAN side of device/box. But looks like adding equipment is not an option. I’m curious if there is an answer to your problem I am unaware of. Such as a Linux feature that can tie a network to a specific process. But from a networking standpoint there is no other answer. You can’t have the same network address on two different networks connected to the same device. It’s a routing conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

This is shot in the dark... what if you strip part of an Ethernet cord and cut the tx wire, the one that sends the data? maybe that could resolve the listen only requirement lol.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. I just stumbled upon it.

Appleoddity is (in the comments) on the right track that you need a router that does NAT to access the normal LAN and bridge to access the special device. However this doesn't have to be a physical router. You could run a router as a virtual machine inside the Linux box. (The host doesn't even need to have an ip-address on the 10 Gb/s interface so it won't see any conflict.) Performance may be an issue though.

If you go the VM route anyway another, conceptually somewhat simpler, solution present itself:
Just put the Linux application inside a VM with 2 virtual network interfaces. 1 bridges directly on the 10 Gb/s adapter (again, host doesn't need ip-address on this NIC), the other uses NAT to the LAN interface.
I suggest to use bridge for the 10 Gb/s because of performance reasons.

This is all assuming that the Linux machine is beefy enough to handle this.

Comment: I think OP can bridge 2 adapters directly, without running virtual router. Since one device is read-only IP collision should not happen and it should not impact network communication.

Comment: @dmmedia I seriously doubt if that would work without causing some serious side-effects on the Linux machine. You essentially have an ip-address conflict between the device and the default gateway. This would really mess with the arp-tables.

Comment: Device probably would not respond or it can be possible to block ARP responses from the interface device conncted to.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is we don't control the network.  We can't add any hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for trying to help.  The good news for me is the manufacturer of the hardware rendered the problem moot by updating their firmware and allowing us to change the IP.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.